# How do I get the maven repository for DynamicJasper 3.1.2 (or higher)?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

How do I get the maven repository for DynamicJasper 3.1.2 (or higher)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <repository>
        <id>djmaven2</id>
        <url>http://www.fdvs.com.ar/djmaven2</url>
        <name>DynamicJasper public Repository</name>
    </repository>
```

and the dependencies are :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

please use this repository: http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/

if you don't see the latest version, dont worry, it will be pulled from another internal repository.

Comment: FYI, this repo appears to be dead now.

Comment: This is really old. Use central repo. All artifacts will be there

Answer (score 1):

Also remember to include the **repository** declaration that Andrew menction in his answer under the **repositories** tags inside pom.xml